# How to call web service by POST METHOD

Tags: php

I'm studying programming. I have a php File in my XAMPP, this File is use to insert data to my database.

I want to use post method to call php File and execute sql string.

my PHP file:

```
<?php
$DB_HostName = "localhost"; // ten host
$DB_Name = "QM_TEST";           
$DB_User = "root";          
$DB_Pass = "";              
$DB_Table = "Customer";             

$name = $_GET[@"name"];
$address = $_GET[@"address"];

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (name, address) values('$name','$address');";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else
?>
```

Comment: what has this to do with OSX or Cocoa?

Comment: It's not related to OSx and it's not very clear what is the problem that you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `[stream_context_create()][1]` if you don't want to use cURL.

Here's an example:

```
    $url = 'http://server.com/path';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php).